# $f$ is non-constant, entire, takes real values on intersecting lines, show: the angles between the lines are rational multiples of $\pi$

Tags: complex-analysis

**Question:** Assume the non constant entire function $f$ takes real values on two intersecting lines in the complex plane. Prove that the measure of either angle formed by the lines is a rational multiple of $\pi$.

**My attempt:** I am very stuck on this problem. So, the first thing that I did was say that we can consider the case where the lines cross on the origin, and one of the lines is the real axis, because we can always just consider $\alpha f + c$, where $\alpha $ and $c$ are constants in $C$, instead of $f$, and the result should be the same. Let $\alpha$ be the angle between the lines.

From here, I'm not really sure what to do. I keep trying to use the argument principle, because it at least involves integers, which I was hoping I could somehow use to get the rational multiple of $\pi$ part of the argument. In particular, I've been trying to apply the argument principle on the sector of the circle whose angle is $\alpha$, and where one of the sides is on the real axis. But I'm not really getting anywhere.

A hint in the right direction would be very useful. Thank you!

Comment: Do you know the Schwarz reflection principle?

Comment: @zhw., I do, but I'm unsure of how it applies to this problem... as I know it, the theorem states that if we have a symmetric connected set, and a holomorphic, real-valued function $f$ on the section of the set in the upper half-plane that extends continuously to the section of the set in the lower half-plane, there is a holomorphic function that agrees with $f$ in the whole set. Can you give me a hint on how this applies to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(z)=\sum a_nz^n=\sum a_nr^ne^{in\phi}$, where $z=re^{i\phi}$. For $\phi=0$ the series is real and hence all $a_n$ are real (as the derivatives at zero of the real-valued function $\sum a_nr^n$). If the series is real for some $\phi=\phi_0$, then, by the same pattern, all coefficients $a_ne^{in\phi_0}$ are real. The function is nonconstant, and so there exists an $n>0$ such that $a_n\ne0$. Since $a_n$ is real and $a_ne^{in\phi_0}$ is real, we conclude that $e^{in\phi_0}$ is real. But then $n\phi_0$ is an integer multiple of $\pi$. No need to know the reflection principle:)

Comment: Thank you! This is very simple.